# Do flavors other than the standard Gnome Ubuntu 20.10 support Raspberry Pi on the desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, raspberrypi, 20.10

I read recently that Ubuntu officially supports certain Raspberry Pi hardware on the desktop as of version 20.10. See the announcement here: https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-20-10-on-raspberry-pi-delivers-the-full-linux-desktop-and-micro-clouds

I'm wondering if that official support extends to other flavors such as Ubuntu MATE, Lubuntu, etc?

I know that Ubuntu MATE has made images available for Raspberry Pi for a little while, but I was under the impression that was due to extra development done by the Ubuntu MATE team, and it was not "officially" supported by Canonical.

My guess is that the work done by Canonical will benefit many of the other flavors as well, but I was hoping someone here could confirm.

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: I don't know why the other flavors are not available as ARM64 builds - but I know you can install different graphical interfaces on top of Ubuntu Server (on Raspberry Pi), which gives you kind of the same thing.

Comment: Look up https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify which allows you to add whichever Ubuntu *flavor* you like ontop of the Ubuntu Server image. Ubuntu-MATE do have an image, however please note `sddm` has an issue with some pi's (used by Kubuntu & Lubuntu) which `desktopify` currently doesn't cater for.  It's a known issue.

Comment: Possibly relevant: There's [some level of unofficial support](https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi) for RPis in Ubuntu's parent Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by following the instructions on [how to install Ubuntu Server on Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#5-install-a-desktop), namely point 5: Installing a desktop.

The following desktop options are available (I checked [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for Groovy):

Kubuntu:
`sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

Lubuntu:
`sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`

Ubuntu Budgie:
`sudo apt install ubuntu-budgie-desktop`

Ubuntu Mate:
`sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Xubuntu:
`sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`

I didn't find any packages for Ubuntu Kylin or Ubuntu Studio, so I guess those flavors are not available as addon desktop packages for server.

Comment: I selected this answer because it seemed the most official answer as it was on the Ubuntu website.

Answer (score 8):

Look up https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify which allows you to add whichever Ubuntu *flavor* you like on top of the Ubuntu Server image.

Desktopify does more than just add the desktop (allowing for some differences in the pi to amd64 boxes, plus desktop versus server).

> ```
> Put an Ubuntu Server image for Raspberry Pi on a SDHC card.
> Boot the Ubuntu Server SDHC on a Raspberry Pi 2, 3 or 4.
> Login to the Raspberry Pi; username ubuntu and password ubuntu
>     You will be prompted to change the password
> Clone the project
>     git clone https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify.git
> Change your current directory to desktopify directory
>     cd desktopify
> Convert the server to a desktop
>     sudo ./desktopify --de ubuntu-mate
> ```

Ubuntu-MATE do have an image (just released).

Please note `sddm` has an issue with some pi's (used by Kubuntu & Lubuntu) which `desktopify` currently doesn't cater for.  It's a known issue.

Comment: I can't find a link for the pi image for Ubuntu-MATE 20.10. It hit my inbox earlier in the day, but I don't currently see it (and won't need it till the weekend).  I can't recall if was just a beta/RC or actual release.

Comment: Running regular Ubuntu MATE desktop on RPi (4 in my case) is good too.

Comment: This is a great response with very helpful links. I believe the developer of this project is an Ubuntu employee, so that helps add credibility to its functionality.

Comment: @CitizenUnderdog a number of the contributors to `desktopify` are Canonical employees (work on it can be seen on youtube), and Martin Wimpress is the head of Ubuntu Desktop (a co-creator of Ubuntu-MATE, ....etc)   For prior releases it was as simple as `apt install *wanted*-desktop` however there are differences with how Server works, plus the pi in later releases so a lot more needs to be done.  `desktopify` just does all those things known to be needed, plus installs the desired desktop. Look up the history of the `desktopify` project and you'll see many flavor people involved too...

Comment: Further note to my prior comment, whilst there maybe Canonical employees, they are community members when they work on that *Ubuntu community* project, ie. Martin & others are doing it in their free time (just as Martin does Ubuntu-MATE in his free time) and thus the Canonical employees really has no bearing.  It could be placed on a Ubuntu wiki page (the only ref. I see is on Martin's own page; signed note by community member), but that's more work (easy to put there, but needs updating whenever changes are made)