# How to install GUI to Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: server, raspberrypi

I have installed the CLI OS for the Ubuntu Server onto my Raspi 4 4GB, but when I try to install a GUI to work in, I am sent back to a screen that is in CLI, but I can't type or perform any functions.

To install I used *sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop* command.

Does this mean that my OS is corrupted or have I made a mistake in the install of the GUI? Alternatively, is it better to just use the CLI for a server?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1303995/edit) and add how exactly did you try to install a GUI? It is best to copy the exact command and it's output/errors from the terminal into the question and then format the pasted text as code using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: Now that you have installed `ubuntu-desktop`, can you open the GUI from the CLI with the command `startx`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The screen I am presented with remains the same with startx, I've also tried to do sudo reboot to no avail.

Comment: did you do a "sudo apt update" "sudo apt -y upgrade" before installing the desktop ?

Comment: Seems to me a fresh install with a desktop version would have saved you a lot of grief.

Comment: @Koen yes I have tried that.

Comment: @David Probably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do flavors other than the standard Gnome Ubuntu 20.10 support Raspberry Pi on the desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289305/do-flavors-other-than-the-standard-gnome-ubuntu-20-10-support-raspberry-pi-on-th)

Comment: I was going to answer what I'd do (ie. use `desktopify` which does more than just add the `ubuntu-desktop` package), but it's easier for me to mark duplicate, so I've done so.  As `desktopify` is open source code, you can easily see what else you need to do, but just using it would be my recommendation (it was written by Martin Wimpress, current head of Ubuntu Desktop, and head of Ubuntu-MATE team, and has had other *flavors* involved with it too)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me a fresh install with a desktop version would have saved you a lot of grief.

Comment: if you like the answer accept it please.

Comment: I'd also suggest a new install of a distro with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article:
https://linuxhint.com/install-ubuntu-desktop-20-04-lts-on-raspberry-pi-4/
It shows Possible to do that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223997)